# Yeoman placeholder in javascript files

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

How can I use a `placeholder` in `Yeoman` for a `js` file ? i tried to add it

```
  writing: function () {
    this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath('portanova_template'),
      this.destinationPath(this.projectName)

    );
    if(this.answer) {
      this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath('externalTemplate'),
        this.destinationPath(this.projectName+'/app'),
       {
        title: this.projectName
      }
      );
    }
  },
```

and in the js File just added

```
"<%= title %>"
```

wherever needed. But it doesn't seems to work..
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this.fs.copyTpl()` otherwise the template tags are not processed.